# Keep div open through page changes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, reload

I've been trying to have a div 'footer' stay at the bottom of the page, and stay open through page changes. I have achieved this by using JQuery's .load function on a main content div, however, using that method, when someone goes to a different page, the URL stays the same. Is there a way to keep the links changing the URL, but keep the div open? I plan on playing music through said div, so it can't close between page switches, or the music will stop/have to rebuffer.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with HTML5 using:

```
window.history.pushState(obj, "Title", url);
```

after your `.load()` call.

It'll change the displayed URL to match the one in the call, but only URLs that belong to the same domain are permitted.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

Comment: That doesn't want to work for me for some reason. Most likely compatibility issues. I was going to post my code, but being new here, I can't seem to get it to format correctly.

Comment: just put four spaces in front of your code, or paste it, select it, then press the `{}` button.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use frames and hash urls if you want to support non-HTML5 browsers.  I'd use an old-fashioned frameset.  (I can't believe I'm actually suggesting a frameset. It's considered bad practice, and I haven't written code like this in probably 11 years, but in this case, it actually seems like the right solution.  You could use iframes, but I think a frameset actually makes more sense.)

```
<frameset border="0" rows="*,100">
    <frame src="/mainPage" id="content" />
    <frame src="/footer" id="footer" />
</frameset>
```

Use [Ben Alman](http://benalman.com/)'s [hashchange plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/), and use a script like this to manage the page navigation:

```
$(function () {
    $("frame").load(function () {
        document.title = w.document.title;
        var links = $("a[href]", this.contentWindow.document);
        links.attr("target", "_top");
        links.click(function (e) {
            if (this.hostname == location.hostname) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var path = this.pathname.replace(/^[^\/]/, "$&/");
                location.hash = "#" + path + this.search + this.hash;
            }
        });
    });
    var w = $("#content")[0].contentWindow;
    $(window).hashchange(function () {
        var hash = location.hash.substr(1) || "/mainPage";
        var contentLoc = w.location.pathname + w.location.search + w.location.hash;
        if (hash.toLowerCase() != contentLoc.toLowerCase()) {
            w.location.replace(hash);
        }
    }).trigger("hashchange");
});
```

Demo: http://jumpingfishes.com/framed/

As an alternative to frames, you could use AJAX to reload the content, but frames may be quicker to implement.

Comment: +1 Sweet example gilly3! (btw, that's what plugins are for, right?! :)