# How to focus on a previously opened window using window.open()

Tags: javascript, popup, window

I would like to open a popup window for a website and keep it for a music player to be able to play seamless music while the user is navigating across pages.

What I would like to achieve is that when the user **first clicks the "Music" button a new popup window opens** using `window.open` (done). The second part would be that when the user navigates to other pages and clicks again on the "Music" button then the **already open window receives the focus** but doesn't load again.

However what is happening is that as soon as the user navigates away from the original page then the **browser forgets that the window has been opened and the focus() stops working**. It seems that focus() works as far as the user is staying on the same page.

I have found a similar question and tried to implement my code based on that question:

[JavaScript window.open only if the window does not already exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/528671/javascript-window-open-only-if-the-window-does-not-already-exist)

Here is the code I have written so far:

```
$('a.music').click(function(){
        if(typeof(winRef) == 'undefined' || winRef.closed){
            winRef = window.open(this.href,'Music','left=20,top=20,width=500,height=500,toolbar=0,location=0,directories=0,status=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=0,resizable=1,titlebar=0');
        } else {
            winRef.focus();
        }
        return false;
    });
```

Here is the live site if you would like to have a look.
http://ilhaamproject.com/

**How should I reference the opened window such that it works across different page-loads?**

Comment: FYI: Some browsers (e.g. Firefox) block re-focusing window calls from JavaScript because of shifty advertiser popups.  There is a config setting to alter this, but the default is that JS can't raise/lower windows.

Comment: I don't understand. For me Firefox works perfectly, and I'm using the default configuration. Firefox 8.0 / Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** I take my earlier answer back.  This can be done.  Just have the opened window set `winRef` on its opener.  In your popup window, put this code:

```
setInterval(function()
{
    opener.winRef = window;
}, 500);
```

That's it!

There may be some event you can hook on the opener window so you don't have to use the `setInterval`, but I'm not sure.

---

Original answer:

<s>You cannot - JavaScript variables are gone after the script's page is unloaded.  The only way you could do this would be to not unload the page that opened the popup.</s>  You can keep the page open, but change its content using AJAX.  Or you can use the [frames technique I suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8565211/keep-div-open-through-page-changes/8566935#8566935) for a similar question last week.

Comment: Thanks. Isn't there a way to check if there is a window opened with title = ... or URL = ...? This way I could pick one from the available windows, or is it not allowed to read the list of open windows?

Comment: @zsero - I came up with a better way to do it.  See my updated answer.

Comment: It still doesn't work for me. I'm just a beginner in JS, maybe I'm doing something wrong. Here is how I implemented yours: http://pastebin.com/7m8g8Phv

Comment: @zsero - Make sure the `setInterval` code is in the popup window's page.  If the popup window's page is not hosted on the same domain as its parent, it won't work because of the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).  You could probably overcome that by using an iframe.

Comment: Thank you very much! I would have never figured out this myself. I implemented an iframe + script and now it works perfectly! Thanks!